# Основной контент прилип к Header

Tags: html, css, header

Начал писать сайт, нашел в тырнетах адаптивную шапку сайта, прикрутил. Начал добавлять основой контент, но он просто прилип к шапке. Пытался добавить отдельный класс для этого, но не помогает.
Как сделать так, чтобы контент отображался под шапкой и при этом адаптивность на маленьких экранах не пострадала.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
    background: url(https://phonoteka.top/uploads/posts/2022-01/1643225140_1-phonoteka-org-p-ochen-chernii-fon-1.jpg)
no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

header {
  width: 100%;

  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  height: 70px;
}

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: #ffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #012921;
  color: #ffff;
}

.header a.active {
  background-color: #053e37;
  color: #ffff;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }
}

.main_cont {
  margin-top: 80px;
  color: #ffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&family=Roboto&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Тут явно что-то написано</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="header">
      <a href="#" class="logo">Шапка лого</a>
      <div class="header-right">
        <a class="active" href="#">Главная</a>
        <a href="#">Зачет</a>
        <a href="#">Расписание</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main_cont">
      <h1>Сайт1</h1>
      <p>Всякая ересь</p>
    </div>


    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что значит прилип к шапке?

Comment: Из-за того, что вы злоупотребляете float'ами, высота header получилась ноль. Рекомендую попробовать переверстать всё с помощью flexbox, флоаты это прошлый век

Comment: .main_cont --> clear: both;

Comment: clear: both помог, спасибо
К тому, чтобы переверстать на флексбокс прислушаюсь